# How to get the fieldValue in the Meteor AutoForm

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

By meteor autoform,

I can get the label by

```
{{> afFieldLabel name="myLabelName"}}
```

I can also automatically generate a input field by

```
{{> afFieldInput name="myLabelName"}}
```

What if I only want to show the value of the field? I expect there should be something like

```
{{> afFieldValue name="myLabelName" }}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is late.  I'm sure you already figured this out, but here you go anyway.  This will get you the field name (reactively):

var someValue = AutoForm.getFieldValue("fieldName" , "formId");

Then you can place this value anywhere you like within your template.

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't find this api. It's much better than the one I hacked.

Comment: Its actually var someValue = AutoForm.getFieldValue("fieldName", "formId");

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once. Helped me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should use:

`var someValue = AutoForm.getFieldValue("fieldName");`

in your template helpers. If you omit formId, form value will not behave correctly after a page reload. See https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/devel/CHANGELOG.md#500 for reference:

> Compatibility break: The function signature for AutoForm.getFieldValue
>   is reversed from (formId, fieldName) to (fieldName, [formId]) with
>   formId optional. You must not pass the formId argument when using it
>   in a helper that is run within the context of the form. Conversely,
>   you must pass formId if not calling it within an autoform.